# Restoring my tkinter project to funtionality

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on my project and everything was working perfectly. Suddenly the interpreter is giving the error

> from tkinter import _flattern, _join, _stringify, _splitdict
> ImportError:cannot import name '_flattern', from 'tkinter' (path to my
> file directory)

All of my program files from all projects that i am using tkinter are showing the same error

Comment: Did you named a file in your CWD(current working directory) *tkinter* ?

Comment: Did you mean `_flatten` instead of `_flattern`? Also modules/function that start with `_` aren't meant to be used by you. They are part of the main library and it is the only one that should call them.

Comment: @Atlas435 i just checked and they is none,but it used to run without one, but for the sake of progressing what should i do then?

Comment: @TheLizzard  its flatten.anyway to resolve the issue?